# Finding common value pairs between column pairs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 columns A - D.

I need to treat them as pairs (A&B) + (C&D).
I need to find common pairs between both lists, then output them as it's own list (for example in another column pair).

I've been trying to use Vlookup and index max to achieve this but haven't gotten very far.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, how I would go about implementing a formula for this?

EDIT (clarity)

The data looks like this:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: You probably need array formulas to do the testing and return an array of the relevant row numbers.  If you need more help, please post examples of data and desired output, along with what you have tried that didn't work (sometimes that gives clues to what you really want that may not be apparent in your question).

Comment: At first glance, it appears all of the entries in both pairs of columns are identical.  How would you want to handle this data set?

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 "result" columns respectively with the formulas "=A1&B1" and "=C1&D1"

Then you just need one simple formula to check which cells are similar between the two columns (Countif or vlookup would do the trick)